# A very strange Segmentation fault when I new a space

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When I run my code, there is a segmentation fault.
I use gdb to trace my code and locate the error code below:

```
(gdb)  
30      wgt_indx_src = new int [num_wgts];

(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003735e7201e in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

What's more, the num_wgts is 41472 in my case. I try if it is smaller than 12398 it is ok, but when set it as 12399, there exists a sefmentation fault.

I use the valgrind and get the result below: I want to ask if the last two lines meaning the

same instruction?

```
==19944== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
=19944==    at 0x4A04DAC: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:256)
==19944==    by 0x4039C1: main (main.C:137)
==19944==  Address 0x4C36030 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 65,536 free'd
==19944==    at 0x4A04DAC: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:256)
=19944==    by 0x4032FB: grid::~grid() (grid.C:208)
==19944==    by 0x403929: main (main.C:127)
```

Comment: You probably corrupted the heap somewhere else in your program by writing off the bounds of a `malloc`'ed object.

Comment: @japreiss : I am sure "wgt_indx_src" is just be defined and not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting the same object twice.
First in:

```
grid::~grid() (grid.C:208)
```

and the Second time by a code statement which results in call to `delete []` at:

```
main.C:137
```

Deleting the same object twice results in **Undefined Behavior** and corrupts your heap.

Show us your `main()` especially the code between lines `127` to `137`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried running under valgrind? If you have memory corruption the time of corruption and the time of error can often be far apart.

Imagine some seldom used structure that gets stomped on. Everything will be fine until you try to use that structure, at which time everything will fall apart. You almost certainly had a memory problem earlier in your code.